# Add custom color to ckeditor of hippo cms

Tags: plugins, ckeditor, config, hippocms

How do I add a custom colour to ckeditor in hippo cms?
I've gone through tutorials and documentation of both, Hippo CMS and CKEditor but saw that config.js file is missing in the present project. 
 After going through the documentation all I was able to find was:
 -> ckeditor-optimized.jar file in which I'm unable to add plugins 
 -> plugin folder which does not contain colorbutton, even though it shows in the ckbuilder that it is present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"color button" is packaged with the Bloomreach CKeditor instance. It is disabled by default. According to [1] you can enable it by adding

```
{
  extraPlugins: 'colorbutton'
}
```

to the ckeditor configuration [2]

[1] https://documentation.bloomreach.com/library/concepts/document-types/html-fields/ckeditor-plugins.html
[2] https://documentation.bloomreach.com/library/concepts/document-types/html-fields/ckeditor-configuration-properties.html

Comment: Thank you for the lead on this issue. 
Where do I exactly add this line of code? 
I am unable to find the resources or the config folder. I have added maven resources dependencies to the pom.xml file and yet there is no resources folder.

Comment: In the document type editor, edit the document type and click on the rich text field. This can also be configured via the console in the namespace editor template node of the document. I suggest you make the changes through the cms interface.